# What is an efficient method to force uniqueness using rand();

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c++11, random

If I used (with appropriate #includes)

```
int main()
 {
   srand(time(0));
   int arr[1000];
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100000;
      }
   return 0;
 }
```

To generate random 5-digit ID numbers (disregard iomanip stuff here), would those ID numbers be guranteed by `rand()` to be unique? I've been running another loop to check all the values of the array vs the recently generated ID number but it takes forever to run, considering the nested 1000 iteration loops. By the way is there a simple way to do that check?

Comment: They will not be unique. If you want unique why not start at `1` and add one each time?

Comment: @Galik It is not guaranteed either :)

Comment: They will be random within a single run of your app, but they will not necessarily be unique over time. Also note that `time()` has seconds precision, so if you run your app multiple times in the same second, the instances will all start with the same seed value, and thus generate the exact same random sequence.

Comment: put the values in a std::set and if a new value is already there then go get another one

Comment: @RemyLebeau - they will be random, but not unique within a single run

Comment: @pm100: if you call `rand()` enough times in a single process, it will have to eventually return duplicate numbers. `rand()` returns an `int`, and there are only so many unique numbers an `int` can hold.

Comment: What you've posted is an XY problem.  http://xyproblem.info/   A better post would be either asking specifically about how `rand` works or asking how to solve the problem you want solved.  Instead you've asked how a bad attempt at a solution could be made better instead of asking how to make a good solution to the problem.

Comment: How can random be unique! You will randomly get duplicates lol

Comment: `std::random_shuffle`

Comment: @xaxxon I want to know about X and Y.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well `rand()` isn't actually random. Anyways there are random number generating algorithms, like the one posted below by Trevor Hickey, that guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @Zduff: That algorithm does not generate a random number. Not even a pseudo-random one. By definition. It's a good solution for what the OP's actually trying to do, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question was tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11),
you should consider using `<random>` in place of `rand()`.

Using a standard distribution engine,  you can't guarantee that you will get back unique values.  If you use a `std::set`, you can keep retrying until you have the right amount.  Depending on your distribution range, and the amount of unique values you are requesting, that may be adequate.

For example, here is a customized function to get `n` unique values from range `[x,y]`.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template <typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> GetUniqueNumbers(int amount, T low, T high){

    static std::random_device random_device;
    static std::mt19937 engine{random_device()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist(low, high);

    std::unordered_set<T> uniques;
    while (uniques.size() < amount){
      uniques.insert(dist(engine));
    }

    return uniques;
}

int main(){

  //get 10 unique numbers between [0,100]
  auto numbers = GetUniqueNumbers(10,0,100);
  for (auto number: numbers){
    std::cout << number << " ";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is definitely no guarantee `rand` will not produce duplicate numbers, designing it in such a way would not only be expensive in terms of remembering all the numbers it has returned so far but will also reduce its randomness greatly (after it had returned many numbers you could guess what it is likely to return from what it had already returned so far).

If uniqueness is your only goal, just use an incrementing ID number for each thing. If the numbers must also be arbitrary and hard to guess you will have to use some kind of random generator or hash, but should make the numbers much longer to make the chance of a collision much closer to 0.

However if you absolutely must do it the current way I would suggest storing all the numbers you have generated so far into a `std::unordered_map` and generating another random number if it is already in it.

Comment: Also, if `rand()` only returned unique values, it would not be able to return any more values once it had returned `RAND_MAX` number of values, making it pretty useless to use over time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly so, which is what I was trying to get at but you put it much more clearly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Many compilers implement `rand()` with a simple linear congruential generator.  LCG's do exactly what you claim they can't - if they actually produce a random seeming permutation of the integers between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, then `RAND_MAX` is called the cycle length of the generator.  A poorly designed generator will cycle sooner than that.

Comment: @pjs: I didn't say anything about *when* it would cycle around, only that it would *eventually*.  It could cycle around many times and still produce unique values, but *eventually* it is going to cycle around and return a duplicate number that it already returned earlier.

Comment: @RemyLebeau LCG's have the property that they produce *no* duplicates until they hit their cycle length, and then it's *all* duplicates, and in exactly the same order, from that point on.  That's what makes it a cycle.  In fact, the graph-theoretic view of LCG's is that they're a singly linked circular list of permutations of integers, and that seeding the LCG is just deciding where you want to climb on the merry-go-round.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I actually implemented a RNG that returned unique results or called abort() if there were no more unique possibilities, for a similar question to this, but nobody got the joke and I think it still has zero votes.  Most people see an implicit "until there are no unique values left" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, because any guarantee about the output of a random source makes it less random.

There are specific mathematical formulas that have the behavior known as a random permutation. This site seems to have quite a good write-up about it: http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/

Comment: Nonsense.  Every continuous distribution places guarantees on the relative long-term proportion of outcomes in various ranges, that's what a density function is.  A triangular distribution, for example, is no less random for being constrained to have a triangular density function, and to produce no results outside its specified range.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common uniqueness guarantee in most PRNGs, but it won't help you here.  A generator will typically iterate over a finite number of states and not visit the same state twice until every other state has been visited once.

However, a state is not the same thing as the number you get to see.  Many states can map to the same number and in the worst possible case two consecutive states could map to the same number.

That said, there are specific configurations of PRNG that can visit every value in a range you specify exactly once before revisiting an old state.  Notably, an LCG designed with a modulo that is a multiple of your range can be reduced to exactly your range with another modulo operation.  Since most LCG implementations have a power-of-two period, this means that the low-order bits repeat with shorter periods.  However, 10000 is not a power of two, so that won't help you.

A simple method is to use an LCG, bitmask it down to a power of two larger than your desired range, and just throw away results that it produces that are out of range.